# How to prove this property of the L-smooth and μ-strongly convex function?

Tags: convex-optimization

In the descend method,
for the fixed step size$h=2/{L+\mu}$,
we have$f(x^+)-f(x^*)\leq(K_f-1/K_f+1)(f(x)-f(x^*))$，where$K_f=L/\mu$
I am a fresh man

Comment: I don't see any question being asked.